# Invalid CSS after "$newList: list": expected selector or at-rule, was ".append($list1,...")"

Tags: html, css, sass

No puedo utilizar cosas de otros archivos o utilizas librearias como sass:list o sass:map porque me manda error

> "error sass/index.scss (Line 8: Invalid CSS after "$newList: list": expected selector or at-rule, was ".append($list1,...")"

He seguido algunas cosas pero no me resulta igual.

```
@use 'sass:math';

@function pixelestoEmn($pixeles) {
    $emValue: $pixeles / 16px;
    @return $emValue + em;
}
```